# Power BI buscar número especifico dentro de una columna

Tags: powerbi

Estimados necesito ayuda con lo siguiente.

Tengo una tabla en POWER BI en la cual necesito buscar en una columna que contiene solo números un numero especifico por ejemplo:

La columna FCC necesito filtrar solo por el numero 2. Como se puede realizar?

```
FCC
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Filtrar? Puedes añadir un objeto visual tipo tabla y aplicar a ese objeto un filtro para el campo FCC que sea igual a 2. Así lograrás que sólo se muestre el número 2 en la tabla.